# Incorrect timer incrementation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the code below for a simple timer UI in Unity. I am trying to force the timer to update in increments of 0.01 seconds exactly, then reset at 8 seconds. When playing the script I see the timer increments 0.011 seconds. In unity itself I have set Fixed Timestep = 0.01. Why is this going wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UI_Time : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text uiText;
    private int curStep = 0;
    private double timer = Variables.timer;


    // Trying fixed update as an attempted workaround
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        timer += Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        if (timer > 8)
            {
                timer = 0d;
            }
        else
        {
            uiText.text = "Time: " + timer.ToString(".0##");  //Set the text field
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: See also floating point error.

Comment: unity will update as fast as it can, but it doesn't guarantee precisely 100 frames a second

Answer (score 3):

[`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) is actually only used for the Physics and you should not change its intervals for what you want to do ...

rather use [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) and `Time.deltaTime` if possible. Even in `FixedUpdate` it is recommded to use `Time.deltaTime` (see [`Time.fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html))

---

In your case, however, for incrementing in exact timesteps you might consider a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) with [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) (or maybe [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html)) like

```
using System.Collections;

//...

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(RunTimer());
}

private IEnumerator RunTimer()
{
    var time = 0f;
    uiText.text = "Time: " + time.ToString("#.0##");

    // looks scary but is okey in a coroutine as long as you yield somewhere inside
    while(true)
    {
        // yield return makes the routine pause here
        // allow Unity to render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        //
        // WaitForSeconds .. does what the name says
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);

        time += 0.01f;
        uiText.text = "Time: " + time.ToString("#.0##");
    }
}
```

---

[image]